# How can I change array key for specific array value

Tags: php

I have an multidimensional array like this:

```
Position 0: {id=5, name=john}
Position 1: {id=7, name=frank}
Position 2: {id=9, name=tina}
```

What I'm trying to do is:
Change the Position Key (0,1,2) to id value for each one!

```
Position 5: {id=5, name=john}
Position 7: {id=7, name=frank}
Position 9: {id=9, name=tina}
```

I tried to use "array_flip" according to PHP Doc. But I did not succeed! But I just found reference for unidimensional arrays. Like this:

```
<?php
$input = array("oranges", "apples", "pears");
$flipped = array_flip($input);    
print_r($flipped);
?>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple oneliner:

```
$new_array = array_combine(
    array_column($your_array, 'id'),    // these are keys
    $your_array                         // these are values
);
```

Comment: I like that you expanded the one-liner to multiple lines to include the explanation of the arguments.

Comment: I would make it: `$new_array = array_combine(
    array_column($your_array, 'id'), array_column($your_array, 'name'));` making the array  flat since the ID is the key anyways.